# Gtk-warning cannot open display

Tags: gtk, vps

I run ubuntu 10.04 and I'm trying to disable suspend and hibernate mode so I typed this:
Code:

> sudo gedit  /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy

but I get this error:
Code:

> Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: ... does `gksudo gedit...` make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

for graphical applications, such as gedit, you should use gksu

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
```

alternately, you can try nano

```
sudo nano /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
```