# Gtk-warning cannot open display Windows Ubuntu

Tags: windows, gtk, gedit, microsoft

As a classroom for learning Unix/Linux, I'm using Microsoft's Ubuntu App in Windows 10. I want to run:

```
gedit somefile.txt
```

But I get the following:

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gedit:27829): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

None of the following solutions have worked:

1. As per [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103706/gtk-warning-cannot-open-display) I tried `gksu gedit` and just get the final line of the above error, and I tried `sudo nano` and can edit the file (but isn't really a solution as I want to use gedit).
2. As per [@WinEunuuchs2Unix's solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018) I downloaded VcXsrv, added `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` to ~/.bashrc, installed ubuntu-desktop and yad and still get my original error when trying to open gedit.
3. As per [this page](https://dev.to/david_j_eddy/run-linux-gui-applications-on-windows-10-3130) I installed Xming and vim-gtk and tried `gvim` instead of gedit and get:

   E233: cannot open display
4. I followed [this PC world tutorial](https://www.pcgamer.com/linux-in-windows-10/#comment-jump) probem-free up until `dbus-launch --exit-with-session ~/.xsession`, which gives me:

   /usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :0.0
   xrdb: Connection refused
   xrdb: Can't open display ':0.0'
   xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
   Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.

And now I don't know what else to try, so I'd love some help! I also hope this is a good question and apologize if I'm making a typical newbie error.

Comment: Did you try the `xhost +` command?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I didn't as it wasn't in the instructions I tried. So I just opened the Ubuntu app now and directly entered xhost + and xhost +myusername but in both cases I get xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0". So it didn't help but does that help diagnose the issue?

Comment: See [this answer on github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4106#issuecomment-876470388). Also, this question may be better suited for the https://superuser.com/ where questions about Windows are more on topic. Also, see [this related question on unix.stackexchange.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860208/wsl-2-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10-bash-shell-erro). However, pay attention because answers/questions about this topic on WSL1 do not necessarily apply to WSL2 — you are most likely using WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend `xhost +` which is potentially dangerous as it lets anyone in the universe to connect to your X session, but you can run that then run your command, after the software starts up then run `xhost -` so you will be secure again. Thats a temprary workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu app uses WSL which is primarily a text-based system, it does not provide a full-featured graphical desktop environment.
However, since quite a while WSL is capable of running graphical applications in a window. The necessary steps on the installation and instructions how to use can be found in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps).

If you are looking for a full-featured desktop, you may want to consider installing Ubuntu in a virtual machine, like e.g. Microsoft Hyper-V.